# Difference Between scrollY and scrollTop

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between scrollY and scrollTop 
What is difference between scrollX and scrollLeft

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
    console.log(document.querySelector('html[lang="en"]').scrollTop) //Same Result
    console.log(window.scrollY)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

**scrollY/X** - (based on window) *The read-only scrollY property of the Window interface returns the number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled vertically. You can get the number of pixels the document is scrolled horizontally from the scrollX property.*

**scrollTop/Left** - (based on element) *The scrollLeft and scrollTop properties return the number of pixels that the element’s content is scrolled from its left and top edges.*

The first uses the window object while the later uses the DOM element.

**`Mozilla`** -> NOTE: **When **`scrollTop`** is used on the root element (the **`<html>`** element), the **`scrollY`** of the window is returned. This is a special case of scrollTop.**

So in your instance, it seems there is no difference when used on the root `html` element.

Answer (score 1):

ScrollTop is basically can be get and set, where as scrollY of window's only can be get. ScrollTop is Element's property where as ScrollY is of Window's property.